# Input dimensions for distance function for nearest neighbors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

In the context of unsupervised nearest neighbors with `scikit-learn`, I have implemented my own distance function to deal with my uncertain points (i.e. a point is represented as a normal distribution):

```
def my_mahalanobis_distance(x, y):

'''
x: array of shape (4,) x[0]: mu_x_1, x[1]: mu_x_2, 
                        x[2]: cov_x_11, x[3]: cov_x_22
y: array of shape (4,) y[0]: mu_ y_1, y[1]: mu_y_2,
                        y[2]: cov_y_11, y[3]: cov_y_22 
'''     

    cov_inv = np.linalg.inv(np.diag(x[:2])+np.diag(y[:2]))
    return sp.spatial.distance.mahalanobis(x[:2], y[:2], cov_inv)
```

However, when I set my nearest neighbors:

```
nnbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric='pyfunc', func=my_mahalanobis_distance)
nearest_neighbors = nnbrs.fit(X)
```

where `X` is a `(N, 4) (n_samples, n_features)` array, if I print `x` and `y` in my `my_mahalanobis_distance`, I get shapes of `(10,)` instead of `(4,)` as I would expect.

Example:

I add the following line to `my_mahalanobis_distance`:

```
print(x.shape)
```

Then in my main:

```
n_features = 4
n_samples = 10
# generate X array:
X = np.random.rand(n_samples, n_features)
nnbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric='pyfunc', func=my_mahalanobis_distance)
nearest_neighbors = nnbrs.fit(X)
```

The result is:

```
(10,)
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (8,8) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 8 (dim 0)
```

I perfectly understand the error, but I do not understand why my `x.shape` is `(10,)` while my number of features is `4` in `X`.

I am using **Python 2.7.10** and **scikit-learn 0.16.1**.

EDIT:

replacing `return sp.spatial.distance.mahalanobis(x[:2], y[:2], cov_inv)` by `return 1` just for testing return:

```
(10,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
```

So only the first call to `my_mahalanobis_distance` is wrong. Looking at the `x` and `y` values at this first iteration, my observations are:

- `x` and `y` are identical
- if I run my code multiple times, `x` and `y` are still identical but their values have change compared to the previous run.
- these values seem coming from a `numpy.random` function.

I would conclude that such a first call is a debugging piece of code which has not been removed.

Comment: Please add a toy example with input, desired output and actual output.

Comment: I just added a toy example.

Comment: Try updating scikit-learn.

Comment: @Nikolas I am not allowed  to update my working environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I customed my `my_mahalanobis_distance` to handle this issue:

```
def my_mahalanobis_distance(x, y):
    '''
    x: array of shape (4,) x[0]: mu_x_1, x[1]: mu_x_2, 
                            x[2]: cov_x_11, x[3]: cov_x_22
    y: array of shape (4,) y[0]: mu_ y_1, y[1]: mu_y_2,
                            y[2]: cov_y_11, y[3]: cov_y_22 
    '''     

    if (x.size, y.size) == (4, 4):        

        return sp.spatial.distance.mahalanobis(x[:2], y[:2], 
                                           np.linalg.inv(np.diag(x[2:]) 
                                           + np.diag(y[2:])))

    # to handle the buggy first call when calling NearestNeighbors.fit()
    else:
        warnings.warn('x and y are respectively of size %i and %i' % (x.size, y.size))
        return sp.spatial.distance.euclidean(x, y)
```

Comment: Could you detail? As my `x` and `y` are expected to be of shape `(4,)` it is not a problem. I could have returned 1, it is just not to raise an error.

Comment: Yes but I enter the `else` statement only once (I have ensured that), during the first call (probably a remaining debugging piece of code). I could have returned whatever suits you instead of euclidean distance.

Comment: Yes. According to the `scikit-learn` documentation: The callable should take two arrays as input and return one value indicating the distance between them

Comment: Cannot access the chat from my office :/. Just tell me what's bothering you.

Comment: My first call, in my opinion due to a remaining debugging piece of code not removed by the maintainers, does not occur when you're running my piece of code with your python3 and `sklearn` versions, right? So, I think that this first call is totally useless (only for debugging purpose), so the result of such a first call has not impact. Thus, I will only compare Mahalanobis distance. I just replaced the euclidean distance by `numpy.nan` and this does not affect my result.

Comment: I deleted my comments to avoid long discussion. Use np.nan and if it runs fine, then all good.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, yet too long for a comment. I can not reproduce the error.

Using:

Python 3.5.2 and 
Sklearn 0.18.1

with the code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
n_features = 4
n_samples = 10
# generate X array:
X = np.random.rand(n_samples, n_features)


def my_mahalanobis_distance(x, y):    
    cov_inv = np.linalg.inv(np.diag(x[:2])+np.diag(y[:2]))
    print(x.shape)
    return sp.spatial.distance.mahalanobis(x[:2], y[:2], cov_inv)

n_features = 4
n_samples = 10
# generate X array:
X = np.random.rand(n_samples, n_features)
nnbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric=my_mahalanobis_distance)
nearest_neighbors = nnbrs.fit(X)
```

The output is

```
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
(4,)
```